# UWP - c # Move json objects (nodes) to another object by drag and drop using ListView?

Tags: c#, json, xaml, listview, uwp

I'm working on a uwp application, I have data loaded from a json and I save it there
what I want is to move child objects that are inside a parent object to another parent object
by drag-and-drop functionality of a listview of the interface

I am using an ObservableCollection to iterate them with a foreach and load data to the list
using listview.ItemsSoure.

I have a lot of doubts like:
* How to know what item I am dragging?
* How to detect in the target listview that I am releasing an item, object, observableCollection?
* how to move the child object to the parent object
but I have no idea where to start
I don't even know if my plan is correct or it doesn't work

my file json data:

```
{
  "date": 737282,
  "notebooks": [
    {
      "title": "Bienvenido",
      "created": 0,
      "notes": [
        {
          "title": "una nota que ya funciona ",
          "id": "SoYnXQslbxDTe",
          "created": 737307,
          "updated": 737309,
          "text": "de forma excepcional"
        },
        {
          "title": "agregar nuevas notas mas eficaces cada vez mas rapidos this is great",
          "id": "HGHQVRgpuvqrqs",
          "created": 737307,
          "updated": 737309,
          "text": ""
        },
        {
          "title": "intrensent and lorem ipsum dolor camen argon ersom",
          "id": "plwjWxOGaHhpg",
          "created": 737307,
          "updated": 737309,
          "text": "indelimit arkenson auk kalemer amred yut hyt"
        } 
      ],
      "id": "section1",
      "updated": 0
    },
    {
      "title": "bnfgdgh",
      "created": 737307,
      "notes": [
        {
          "title": "Bienvenido a la nueva version",
          "id": "eoERbgGDrdxDz",
          "created": 737307,
          "updated": 737309,
          "text": "welcome to new note sample"
        },
        {
          "title": "un item que no puedes reordenar",
          "id": "VSyL_HaV-tdEWz",
          "created": 737307,
          "updated": 737309,
          "text": "gdhgdh"
        }
      ],
      "id": "jwhsEbLMF",
      "updated": 737307
    },
    {
      "title": "Faus inside order",
      "created": 737307,
      "notes": [
        {
          "title": "mi nueva nota",
          "id": "qX-jM_s",
          "created": 737307,
          "updated": 737309,
          "text": ""
        },
        {
          "title": "dfdfd",
          "id": "CDTDjNLQ_",
          "created": 737307,
          "updated": 737309,
          "text": "dfgdfgdf"
        },
        {
          "title": "dfdfd",
          "id": "zhhskohLLEYh",
          "created": 737307,
          "updated": 737309,
          "text": ""
        } 
      ],
      "id": "muNVWlFNbyYdgP",
      "updated": 737307
    }
  ],
  "version": 1
}
```

my model class:

```
public class Notes : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string Title;
        public string title
        {
            get {return Title; }
            set
            {
                Title = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("title");
            }

            }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public int created { get; set; }
        public int updated { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
    public class Notebook
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public int created { get; set; }
        public List<Notes> notes { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public int updated { get; set; }
    }
    public class Libro
    {
        public int date { get; set; }
        public List<Notebook> notebooks { get; set; }
        public int version { get; set; }
    }
```

My listview of which I am going to move:

```
<ListView

                                x:Name="ListaNotas"
                               CanDragItems="True"
                                CanReorderItems="True"
                                AllowDrop="True"
                                IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Mynotes}"

                                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectItem, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

my listview target for drop:

```
<ListView
                            x:Name="listaSections"
                            Margin="0"
                            Padding="0"
                            AllowDrop="True"
                            CanReorderItems="True"
                            CanDragItems="True"
                            IsItemClickEnabled="True"
/>
```

my problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/smkKS.gif

My objective:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWOLw.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to know what item I am dragging?

​
If you want to know what item you are dragging, you need to subscribe DragItemsStarting event in your ListaNotas ListView. It occurs when a drag operation starts.

```
private void ListaNotas_DragItemsStarting(object sender, DragItemsStartingEventArgs e)
{
    viewmodel dragItem = e.Items[0] as viewmodel;
}
```

> How to detect in the target listview that I am releasing an item,
>   object, observableCollection?

In **listaSections** ListView, you should not set AllowDrop to true. In this case, the item you dragged will be added to the listView instead of the listViewItem. So you should set AllowDrop in the child view. For instance, suppose there is only one textBlock in your listViewItem, Then you need to set **AllowDrop**, and subscribe **Drop** and **DragEnter** event. When you release your item, the Drop event will be triggered, you can get the viewmodel from it.

.xaml

```
<ListView x:Name="listaSections"
                            Margin="0"
                            Padding="0"
                            CanReorderItems="True"
                            IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                            ItemsSource="{x:Bind RightLib.notebooks}" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Notebook">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}" AllowDrop="True" Drop="TextBlock_Drop" DragEnter="TextBlock_DragEnter"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

.cs

```
private void SongsListView_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.OriginalSource as TextBlock)?.DataContext is Notebook targetAccount) {
        //targetAccount is Notebook 
    }
}
private void TextBlock_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.AcceptedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Move;
    e.DragUIOverride.Caption = "Move";
}
```

Comment: it worked, although it takes a long time to implement it in the end I succeeded, thanks again